# Get 4 points of a rectangle inside a plane

Tags: geometry, matlab, 3d

There is a plane defined by 3 points in 3D space.

I need to get the 4 edges points of a rectangle that:

- Lies on the plane.
- Has Width and high of w and h.
- Centered at the Z axis.
- One of it side is parallel to the XY plane.

How can I get the 4 edges points using Matlab?

I will update this post with my progress, if I have any.

Comment: Though this does not seems to be homework, please share what you have tried already. Where do you get stuck? And I think this will have rotation symmetry, how should we handle that?

Comment: Any rectangle? Or the particular rectangle whose vertices include the three points that define your plane?

Comment: Any rectangle that lies on the plane. I tried to lock all degrees of freedom now.

Comment: When you say: that one of its sides has to be parallel to the xy coordinate plane, can this side _belong_ to this plane ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I have completely modified my Matlab code in order

1) to simplify it.

2) to fullfill the requirement of a given length and width.

I have removed the previous program because it has no longer interest.

`clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal
P1=rand(3,1);P2=rand(3,1);P3=rand(3,1);w=1.2;h=0.7;
M=[P1,P2,P3];
c=det(M)/det([M(1:2,:);ones(1,3)]);  %kind of Cramer formulas
C=[0;0;c];
V1=P1-C;V3=P3-C;
a=V1(3)/V3(3);V1=V1-a*V3;
N=cross(V1,V3);V2=cross(N,V1);
V1=V1/norm(V1);V2=V2/norm(V2);
S=[C,C,C,C]+[(w/2)*V1,(h/2)*V2]*[1 -1 -1 1;1 1 -1 -1];
I=[1,2,3,4,1];plot3(S(1,I),S(2,I),S(3,I));
plot3(C(1),C(2),C(3),'or');
plot3(M(1,:),M(2,:),M(3,:),'*r')
S1=S(:,1);S2=S(:,2);S3=S(:,3);`

Its principle is as follows.

Let $(P)$ denote the (affine) plane determined by points $P_k$.

Let $(P^*)$ be the vector plane associated with $(P)$ (i.e., parallel to $(P)$ passing through the origin).

Let $ \ C =  (P) \ \cap \ Oz.$ We will go way and back from $(P)$ to $(P^*)$ by substracting or adding $C$.

1) Initial data : points $P_k$, $k=1\cdots3$ and side lengths $w$ and $h$.

2) Define $V_1=P_1-C=\vec{CP_1}$ and $V_3=P_3-C=\vec{CP_3} \ $  (provisional basis for $(P^*)$).

3) First modification of $V_1$ so that it is parallel to xy plane.

4) Computation of  $V_2 \in (P^*)$, orthogonal to $V_1$ (using the two cross products trick)

5) Final orthonormalization of basis $(V_1,V_2)$.

6) The vertices of the rectangle are $S_k = C \pm (w/2)V_1\pm(h/2)V_2$.

**Edit:** Explanations for the Cramer formulas

Let $ux+vy+wz=h$ be the plane equation. The point of intersection $C(0,0,c)$ of $(P)$ with the z-axis has its last coordinate $c=h/w$. This ratio can be transformed into the ratio of two determinants. We start from the system:

$$\begin{cases} 
ux_1 & + & vy_1 & + & wz_1 & = & h \\
ux_2 & + & vy_2 & + & wz_2 & = & h \\
ux_3 & + & vy_3 & + & wz_3 & = & h
\end{cases}$$

The Cramer formula for $w$ is $w=det(S)/det(M)$ with

$$det(M)=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 &  z_1 \\
x_2 & y_2 &  z_2 \\
x_3 & y_3 &  z_3
\end{vmatrix}
\ \ and \ \
det(S)=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 &  h \\
x_2 & y_2 &  h \\
x_3 & y_3 &  h
\end{vmatrix}=h \begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 &  1 \\
x_2 & y_2 &  1 \\
x_3 & y_3 &  1
\end{vmatrix}.$$

Note: For a good recapitulation on determinants, see:

www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/determinants.pdf

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you very much! I wounder if you could explain the steps in more detail or point where I can get more info, like the evaluation of c by two determinants factor.

Comment: Also, a=V1(3)/V1(3);V1=V1-a*V3; V1(3)/V1(3) is always = 1. V1 is not parallel to the xy plane.

Comment: Correction done.

Comment: Nice, got it! Thanks a lot. One last thing (I hope): what concept you used to make V1 parallel to the xy plane?

Comment: I tried to make a combination of vectors of $(P^*)$ (in order to stay there) so that its third coordinate is 0:   it is similar to a step of Gaussian elimination: first divide the coefficient by its value in order to make it 1, then multiply by a convenient value that will make 0 when you substract...